# Drupal 7 deleting node does not delete all associated files

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

One file gets upload when the node is created via standard Drupal.

Later, 2 files are added to the node via:

```
file_save(std Class)
file_usage_add(std Class, 'module', 'node', $node_id)
```

At the end, I end up with 3 entries in file_managed and file_usage.

Problem: when I delete the node via standard Drupal, the file that was added during the initial node creation gets removed, but not the 2 that were added later. These files remain in both tables, and physically on the disk.

Is there some flag that is being set to keep the files even if the node is deleted? If so, where is this flag, and how do I set it correctly (to be removed along with the node)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the [`file_delete()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_delete/7) function, see this comment:

> // If any module still has a usage entry in the file_usage table, the file
> // will not be deleted

As your module has declared an interest in the file by using `file_usage_add()` it will not be deleted unless your module explicitly says it's OK to do so.

You can either remove the call to `file_usage_add()` or implement [`hook_file_delete()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_file_delete/7) and use [`file_usage_delete()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_usage_delete/7) to ensure the file can be deleted:

```
function mymodule_file_delete($file) {
  file_usage_delete($file, 'mymodule');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force deleting of file.

```
file_delete($old_file, TRUE);
```

But make sure that this file is not used in other nodes using:

```
file_usage_list($file);
```

Comment: has a spam link

Comment: @RimuAtkinson, thx. I removed the link. Looks like the linked website got hacked.